# Short story: extraterrestrials visit lunar landing site soon after Apollo 11 flight, examine and return discarded backpacks

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a very short summary of a short story.

Soon after the July 1969 Apollo 11 flight, extraterrestrial(s) examine what was left behind at the landing site. They remove the two backpacks. Those objects are later returned to the site. Plot twist: the ETs inadvertently returned to the site three backpacks, not two. The notion is that the extraterrestial or extraterrestrials (1) did not want to be noticed by Earthlings and (2) made the error of restoring the site with a third backpack that never existed before they produced it.

This may have appeared in *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*. Perhaps someone can identify the title and author, and the issue date.

Comment: I have vague recollections of a cartoon image (single picture) showing either:
Aliens visiting a Apollo landing site and leaving the wrong number of suits or backpacks after investigating the site,
Or Humans revisiting the site later and finding the wrong number of suits/backpacks that the alines had left.

Comment: It is entirely possible that this was a short story, a cartoon, or a multi-panel sequence of cartoons. Not every printed summary is correct.

Comment: Duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223228/short-story-where-aliens-visit-tranquillity-base-and-take-the-discarded-backpack